# how to add java state manager into android studio?

Tags: java, android

i want to make a state manager in my app to manage all my screens.
i looked around on the web and found easyflow as the main one people use in android studio .
in it's site >

https://github.com/Beh01der/EasyFlow/blob/master/README.md

it says you can add it to android studio by modifying dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>au.com.datasymphony</groupId>
    <artifactId>EasyFlow</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

but in JAVA not android studio, (you can't put it like their example in build.gradle) 
so i tried to translate their explanation to this >

```
compile 'au.com.datasymphony:EasyFlow:v1.3.1'
```

and it can't work...
is there another state machine you suggest ? or what am i doing wrong in my code ?

Comment: according to gradle please http://gradleplease.appspot.com/ there is no gradle repository for easyflow sadly

Comment: so do people usually don't use a state machine in android studio ? or is there an alternative ?

Comment: we don't use a state machine in android, because going from one view to another is by sending intents and launching activities, and React is more popular in android than event driven programming

Answer (score 0):

I faced that issue .. After little search I found that version by maven does not point to latest code by demo:

- **https://github.com/Beh01der/EasyFlow by Beh01der** has above issue

However I found that:

- **https://github.com/carrot-garden/state_EasyFlow by carrot-garde** has proper source code but still pointing to wrong repository

That is the reason why I forked second project and changed it into Android project with gradle which contains AppDemo in addition to EasyFlow library:

- **https://github.com/mabuthraa/EasyFlow-Android**

You can use latest one and build your AAR by

```
./gradlew easyflow:Release
```

Good luck,'.